# PHP , Display form

Tags: php

**Question:**

How to display form in such a way that Its always unique for each offer name.
I do not want to redirect form to new page.

```
<?php 
$sqltable = mysql_query("SELECT * from TABLE");
?>

<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="window.location.reload()">
//output truncatted
<table>

<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqltable)) 
       {
        echo "<tr> ";
        echo "<td>" . $row[offername] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[points] . "</td>";
        echo "<td><input type='submit' value='Purchase' name='offername'</td>";
       }
       echo "</tr> ";
?>

</table>
</form>

offername= offer1, offer2 , offer3, offer4, offerN
points   = 100  , 200    , 10     , 50    , xxx
```

**Desired output.**

when submit button is clicked with offer1, is should change its name to offer1 and same goes true for other offernames. or , form should be submitted to respective offername.

Comment: If you don't want to redirect you have to use javasript to do what you want.

Comment: @Javed: Don't spam with irrelevant tags. I removed them now

Comment: which irerelavant tags i used ??? , please specify so that i can remove them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
<?php
$sqltable = mysql_query("SELECT * from TABLE");

//offername= offer1, offer2 , offer3, offer4, offerN
//points   = 100  , 200    , 10     , 50    , xxx

if(isset($_POST['Purchase']) && $_POST['Purchase'] == 'Purchase'){  
    if(isset($_POST['offername']))
        echo 'Submitted offer name is '.$_POST['offername'][0];
    else
        echo 'No offers selected';
}
?>
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="window.location.reload()">

<table>
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqltable)) 
{
echo "<tr> ";
echo "<td>" . $row['offername'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['points'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><input type='radio' name='offername[]' value='".$row['offername']."'></td>";
echo "</tr> ";
}
echo "<tr><td colspan='3'><input type='submit' value='Purchase' name='Purchase'></td></tr>";
?>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work create an input element as array.

```
<?php 
$sqltable = mysql_query("SELECT * from TABLE");
?>

<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="window.location.reload()">
//output truncatted
<table>

<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqltable)) 
       {
        echo "<tr> ";
        echo "<td>" . $row[offername] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[points] . "</td>";
        echo "<td><input type='submit' value='Purchase' name='offername[]'></td>";
       }
       echo "</tr> ";
?>

</table>
</form>

//offername= offer1, offer2 , offer3, offer4, offerN
//points   = 100  , 200    , 10     , 50    , xxx

if(isset($_POST['offername'])){
    $offernameArr=$_POST['offername'];
    foreach($offernameArr as $key => $offername ){
        //your code goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: looks good, how do I know which offername has been clicked, and which code to run for which offername.

Comment: I have tested it ,  in foreach  , echo "Value:$offername , Key: $key";  , It always gives me " Value: Purchase ,  Key: 0  " , does not seem to work

Answer (score 0):

```
//form.php    


 <?php 
    $sqltable = mysql_query("SELECT * from TABLE");
if($_GET['offername']){
$offer = $_GET['offername'];
// now you have desired offer name in $offer you can fetch data from db with given offername in where clause and use here
}
    ?>

    <table>

    <?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqltable)) 
           {
            echo "<tr> ";
            echo "<td>" . $row['offername'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['points'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td><a href='form.php?offername=".$row['offername']."'><input type='submit' value='".$row['offername']."' name='submit'></a></td>";
           }
           echo "</tr> ";
    ?>

    </table>
```